# arrange labels for plots on multiple panels to be in one line in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, axis-labels

I am currently plotting (using Python-x,y 2.7.2.1) with several subplots, and I want to have all the y- labels in one line. Currently they are not, because the tick labels have different sizes. As a demonstration I add this script:

```
    import pylab as P
    import numpy as N

    x = N.linspace(0,2*N.pi,10000)
    y1 = N.sin(x)
    y2 = N.cos(x)*10000

    P.figure()
    ax1 = P.subplot(211)
    P.plot(x,y1,"k-")
    y1 = P.ylabel("$\\sin{(x)}$")
    P.xlim((0,2*N.pi))
    ax2 = P.subplot(212)
    P.plot(x,y2,"k--")
    y2 = P.ylabel("$\\cos{(x)}\\cdot{}10^4$")
    P.xlim((0,2*N.pi))
    P.show()
```

The Result looks like this, please note the labels that are shifted with respect to each other:

[image: two graphs with shifted labels with respect to each other]

I tried to set the label position by using

```
    (x,y) = y2.get_position()
    ax1.yaxis.set_label_coords(x,y)
```

but apparently they use different coorinates, as set_label_coords wants relative coordinates while get_position() seems to yield pixels or something. A desparation try using

```
    y1.set_x(x); y1.set_y(y)
```

did not have any effect. So I said to myself: Ask a specialist - so here I am. Can anyone tell me how to shift the labels, so they are in one line with respect to each other and look as awesome as expected?

I look forward to your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pad the position of the labels with

```
P.ylabel("$\\sin{(x)}$", labelpad=20)
```

and

```
P.ylabel("$\\cos{(x)}\cdot{}10^4$", labelpad=20)
```

with some adjustment, this should achieve what you desire. You can even set it after the plot with

```
ax.yaxis.labelpad = 20
```

The `y` label isn't correctly aligned as the length of the numbers on the `y` axis changes, and shifts the label position. You can fix the size of the number on the `y` axis with

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

def thousands(x, pos):
    'The two args are the value and tick position'
    return '%4.1f' % (x*1e-3)

formatter = FuncFormatter(thousands)

ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

This will guarantee that the length of the numbers on the `y` axis is always 4 characters, and so you can fix the offset of the `y` label for all values. Change the returned string in the `thousands()` function of this doesn't please you!

### Edit

Yet another way to achieve this could be to hard code the position of your labels using [set_label_coords](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_label_coords)

```
ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(0.5, 0.5)
```

I just spotted that method, and it might be of some use to you .. ! (0,0) is (left, bottom), (0.5, 0.5) is (middle, middle) etc.

Comment: I actually do that in my specific program, and the x label is no problem. I left this out here to keep it simple.
For some reason the image just turned up in my post (creepy, isn't it?). So what I would like to achieve, is that the y1 and y2 label share the same left border and not the same distance to the tick labels on the right. Sorry I don't know how to make it more clear, I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, have amended my response.

Comment: Hey, no problem @danodonovan. I appreciate any help I can get!

IMO `P.subplot()` does the same as `fig.add_subplot()`. As you can see in the figure shown above, the y labels are not in line, the graphs are. I look for a way to align not only the graphs but also the y-labels.

Comment: In `add_subplot` CHANGE `211` to `121` etc.

Comment: oh I want the plots arranged as they are, but yes, thats a possibility to solve the problem (: I want the labels to be left-justified with respect to the left image border; but as far as I understand, they have their own bbox they stick to and I cannot make them move in a way that is pleasing the eye and the programmer...

Comment: I think I *finally* understand, sorry again. See response!!

Comment: Oh good :D Yes, the `labelpad` is the way that at some point pleases the eye, but it does not please me programming it fiddling through all setting, redoing it for every time I do a similar plot, although I agree it can work eventually. I would rather prefer to 1. read out the absolute position of the y-labels and then adjust all of them accordingly. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but this works fine for me and pleases the eye. Thank you very much for your effort, I accept your solution. Kudos to you (I cannot upvote due to reputation)

Answer (score 1):

As danodonovan says the set_label_coords is a possible way to do it. I might add that this setting worked well for me.

```
ax7.yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.2, 0.5)
```

The 'trick' is to use a negative number to move the label outside of the plot.

Comment: Very right, thats also how the matplotlib "howto" handles it:
http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#align-my-ylabels-across-multiple-subplots